# Can I create a GCP cluster with different machine types?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'd like to create a cluster with two different machine types.

How would I go about doing this? What documentation is available?

Comment: Asking for documentation tends to get closed under the "asking for recommendations" reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a Google Container Engine cluster.

You can have machines of different types by having more than one [node pool](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/node-pools).

If you are creating the cluster in the Console, start by creating it with one node pool and after it is created edit the cluster to add a second node pool with different instance configuration. This is necessary because the UI only allows one node pool at creation.